# How to replace IP address after comma in linux

Tags: sed, tr

I want to replace IP address after second comma to 92.2.11.1 for all:

```
pr,th-klmndisj,92.2.11.1
da,th-kl532disj,92.2.11.8
fr,th-klmn4532j,92.2.21.2
pr,th-klmn52sj,92.2.11.3
```

Expected View:

```
pr,th-klmndisj,92.2.11.1
da,th-kl532disj,92.2.11.1
fr,th-klmn4532j,92.2.11.1
pr,th-klmn52sj,92.2.11.1
```

Comment: using what language to replace the IP address?

Comment: Everything which will work on Linux, sorry I forget to put that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably meant the *second* comma.

```
sed 's/^\([^,]*,[^,]*,\).*/\192.2.11.1/'
```

Explanation: Search for non-commas, a comma, more non-commas, a coma. The part in `\(...\)` is replaced by itself (`\1`), the rest of the line is thrown out and the new string is printed.

Comment: One thing is when if we have something like that:
pr,th-klmn52sj,92.2.11.1,8.8.8.8
command replace after second comma and next also with that single result 92.2.11.1

Comment: @KalinBorisov: I do not understand. Please, update your question or post a new one including the example input and output as you did in this case.

Comment: <pre>pr,th-klmn52sj,92.2.11.1,8.8.8.8</pre>
everything after second comma is replaced even after third comma.

Comment: @KalinBorisov: Oh, I see. You want to keep the stuff after the third comma. Just replace the `.` in search pattern with `[^,]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed 's/,[^,]*$/,92.2.11.1/g' file
```

**test**

```
kent$  echo "pr,th-klmndisj,92.2.11.1
dquote> da,th-kl532disj,92.2.11.8
dquote> fr,th-klmn4532j,92.2.21.2
dquote> pr,th-klmn52sj,92.2.11.3"|sed 's/,[^,]*$/,92.2.11.1/g'
pr,th-klmndisj,92.2.11.1
da,th-kl532disj,92.2.11.1
fr,th-klmn4532j,92.2.11.1
pr,th-klmn52sj,92.2.11.1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F, '$3="92.2.11.1"' OFS=, file
```

Comment: care to comment your code? A couple of lines commenting it will not harm and help explain what this line does and how

Comment: The interesting thing of that is when I have newline with no data, awk add something like that:

,,92.2.11.1

Comment: <pre>
pr,th-klmn52sj,92.2.11.1

</pre>
When I have added line without nothing that command added it self addtional commas and IP

Comment: If your file contains empty lines, try this:                           $ awk -F, 'NF>2{$3="92.2.11.1"}1' OFS=, file   #NF>2 considers only lines with more than 2 columns.